# Visual Studio 2022 - .NET Standard 2.0 - Razor CSHTML File Won't Build

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2022, .net-standard

I am trying to create a .NET Standard 2.0 library that will hold CSHTML Razor files for templating.  I have tried installing the following libraries:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor

And I also have tried adding the following to my .CSPROJ file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've also gone into my Visual Studio tools/features and made sure to check `.NET Framework project and item templates`.

None of these does any good.  When I go to `Add` > `New Item...`, CSHTML files do not show up in the available templates, and if I try free-hand adding a CSHTML file to the project, all sorts of compile-time build errors are thrown when I build the project.

Comment: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  ...  [PageModel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @quaabaam that is for .NET Core 3 or .NET 5-7. I am looking for .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: @codeMonkey ASP.NET Core cannot target .NET Standard. You’re wasting your time on a fool’s errand.